# https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENDJ-3153 Fixed?

Tags: opendj

I create an admin user, add proxied-auth privilege, but got an error when try the PasswordModifyExtendedRequest with the OPENDJ SDK.

Apparently this is an known issue https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENDJ-3153.

Is this fixed? or any other workaround for this problem?

Thanks a lot.

BR,

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

It is not fixed, since the defect is marked as unresolved.
The PasswordModifyExtended operation is designed to support updating someone else password, therefore it should not need the proxy AuthZ control (and I think the issue is that there's no code to process the ProxyAuthz control with that request).

Comment: Thanks. That make sense.